# Integrating of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's assume that I write change in value of differentiable function $f$ over a time interval at $t$ of infinitesimal length $dt$ as $$df_t = t dt$$ So I basically get simple ODE. The solution I see in a book is to simple integrate that eqaution and then I get the solution $f_t=\frac{1}{2} t^2$. My question is: how is this integration formally made? As far as I know, when I integrate a side of equation, it means that I put in into this expression: $ \int ... dt$. However, I already have in the both side of equations with different variables of integration ($df_t$ and $dt$). So if I followed above logic, I would have $$ \int df_t\ dt = \int tdt \ dt$$ which doesn't have any sense.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should realize that

$$
\int {\rm d}\mu = \mu + c \tag{1}
$$

where $c$ is a constant. Once you agree with this statement, the rest follows immediately, for example, note that

$$
{\rm d}\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2\right) = t~{\rm d}t \tag{2}
$$

So your original equation becomes

$$
{\rm d}f_t \stackrel{(2)}{=} {\rm d}\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2\right) \tag{3}
$$

Integrating at both sides you get

\begin{eqnarray}
\int {\rm d}f_t &=& \int {\rm d}\left(\frac{1}{2}t^2\right) \\
f_t &\stackrel{(1)}{=}& \frac{1}{2}t^2 + c \tag{4}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you @caverac. I agree with your solution, however, I have a question regarding your integration, from (3) to (4). You simply added integral sign and did the calculation. Why are we allowed to do that? I has been taught that when we want to integrate the sides of the equation, we should put integral sign and differential $dt$

Comment: @siwy9 If $f_t =f_t(t)$ then 

$$
{\rm d}f_t = \frac{{\rm d}f_t}{\rm dt} {\rm d}t
$$

You can then write your original expression as 

$$
\frac{{\rm d}f_t}{\rm dt} = t
$$

And then you can apply the rule you know: *multiply by ${\rm d}t$ and integrate at both sides*. Hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: thank you again @caverac. Do all those calculations above in your solution have a mathematical rigorous meaning? I think on ODE lecture few years ago I was told that all such operations are not fully correct in terms of mathematical meaning, but they would lead to correct solution